# How Passing Variable as Struct To Function Using C?

Tags: c, dictionary, struct

I Passing Pointer Variable as Struct To Function `Put()`.

main.c:

```
...
enum VTYPE {VSTRING};
typedef enum VTYPE vtype;
typedef struct Value Value;
struct Value {
 vtype typ;
 int64_t size;
 union {
   char *vstring;
 };
};
...
void Put(_map * map, struct Value *key, void * value){
  _pair * pair = malloc(sizeof(_pair));
  printf("[*]==>%s\n",key->vstring);
  /*
  struct Value *vkey;
  vkey.vstring=malloc(key->size +1);
  //vkey->vstring=malloc(key->size +1);
  //vkey->vstring=key->vstring;
  //pair->key = vkey;
  */
  pair->key = key;
  pair->value = value;
  pair->next = map->items;
  map->items = pair;
  map->size++;
}
...
struct Value** Keys(_map*map){  
  int i = 0;
  struct Value** keys = malloc(map->size * 10);
  _pair * item = map->items;
  while( item ){
    printf("mapkey > %s\n",(item->key)->vstring);
    printf("mapval > %s\n",(item->value));
    keys[i++] = (item->key);
    item = item->next;
  }
  return keys;
}
...
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
Value current;
Value str;
_map * map = newMap();
for (current.vint=1; current.vint<=5;current.vint++)
{
str.vstring=malloc(strlen("Item")+current.vint+1+1);
sprintf(str.vstring,"Item%d",current.vint);
//Put(map,str,str.vstring);
Put(map,&str,str.vstring); ===>this may have problem.`&str`
}
Value** keys = Keys(map);
for (int i = 0; i < map->size; i++)
  printf(" > %d===>%d,%s\n",i,keys[i]->typ,keys[i]->vstring);
printf("\nSize:%d",map->size);
}
```

main.h:

```
...
typedef struct _pair{
   struct Value *key;
   void* value;
   int nvalue;
   struct _pair * next;
} _pair;
...
void mapPut(_map*,struct Value*,void*);
...
struct Value** mapKeys(_map*);
...
```

output:

```
[*]==>Item1
[*]==>Item2
[*]==>Item3
[*]==>Item4
[*]==>Item5

mapkey > Item5
mapval > Item5
mapkey > Item5
mapval > Item4
mapkey > Item5
mapval > Item3
mapkey > Item5
mapval > Item2
mapkey > Item5
mapval > Item1
 > 0===>0,Item5
 > 1===>0,Item5
 > 2===>0,Item5
 > 3===>0,Item5
 > 4===>0,Item5
```

why all `mapkey` is `Item5`?
beacuse in for() loop , `str` variable , every time changed.
but in `mapkey` all is same one.

i try to Pass Variable to `Put()` without Pointer, but Error!

how i can fix this?

Comment: Keeping the problem aside, in `Put(map,&str,str.vstring);` Don't you think `str.vstring` is a redundant parameter. when you're already passing `&str`

Comment: It looks like you might have edited the question with your eventual solution. If you have done so, please [roll it back](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43558642/revisions) to the last good state when it was a question, and put the solution in an answer below. We do not overwrite questions with answers here, since that would produce an answer without a question, which is not useful for future readers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. When you do

```
Put(map,&str,str.vstring); ===>this may have problem.`&str`
```

you are passing the exactly same pointer in all the calls, and as you store the *pointer* all entries will have the same pointer to the very same `Value` object.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Create a new `Value` structure in each iteration (using e.g. `malloc`); Or
2. Copy the structure instead of the pointer (i.e. you have the structure as a *value* and not a pointer in the `_pair` structure)

Comment: Tank You , Fixed. :like: